# Variable scope for global inside functions

Tags: php, oop, global-variables, scope

Let us ignore the bad design and ponder the use of a variable which is global inside a function, but not global in the default namespace:

```
a();

function a() {

    function b() {
        global $x;
        echo $x;
    }

    $x=10;
    b();
}
```

The variable `$x` is not printed to stdout. However, if we declare `global $x` inside function `a()` then it *is* printed to stdout. Is there any way to define `$x` as global inside `a()` (such that it is available in the `b()` function) yet not in scope in the default namespace?

**Edit:** Assume that there is an arbitrarily large number of variables to pass, as such defining them with `use()` or as parameters is not practical.

Comment: It is never a good idea to nest functions; and they're not even nested because both a() and b() will be created in PHP's global scope.... potential problems arise if you try to call a() more than once, because it will tell you that b() is already defined, the code is not obvious to read, there's no need to do it, and variable scope issues occur because you don't understand that b() is not inside the scope of a().... nor is this recognised `oop` despite your tagging it as such

Comment: If you really absolutely need functions inside functions, use closures

Comment: It's also not clear why you don't pass the variable as obvious function parameter.

Comment: Thank you Mark. We can examine this as more of an academic exercise. A coworker has coded something along these lines and I am refactoring it, but I am still interested in this as a portion of the code is rather difficult to refactor and I'm going to leave it for the time being.

Comment: @mario: Because it is not my code! Actually, there are a whole slew of the variables and it is not feasible to have 10+ arguments to the function.

Comment: As an academic exercise: both a() and b() are defined in the global scope.... and normal scope rules apply. $x is local to a() and global in $b; but unless it is global in $a() as well then there is no way of making a:x visible to global:x or b:x

Comment: A potential solution would be to create a class containing both a() and b() as methods, and set $x as an instance (or a static) property of the class... then it would be available to a() and b() methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring bad design or why you're not just passing this as a param, you can use a closure and an anonymous function, *if* you define the arguments before you define the function:

```
function a() {
    $x = 10;

    $b = function() use($x) {
        echo $x; // 10
    };

    $b();
}

a();
echo $x; // Undefined variable
```

Comment: Though clever, this still requires defining each variable in the `use()`. I'll update the question tot address the case of an arbitrarily large number of variables. Thanks.